# Stock UIViewController can't be set as an IBOutlet?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a view-based application and I'd like to make a change to which `UIView` is displayed via my `UIViewController`. I set up an `IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController` and then linked it in Interface Builder, however whenever I make this link the app crashes right on startup with `SIGKILL`. Has anyone ever had any experience with this and is there any alternate way to go about what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're doing it the wrong way around. The nib contains the `UIViewController`, which is synthesized on nib load. The nib also contains the `UIView`, which is linked to the `view` property of the `UIViewController`.

Just add another `UIView` (or derived class thereof) to the nib and link it to the `UIViewController`'s `view` property.

In your view controller, you can access this view through the view property.

Comment: Thanks,now I understand why it's called <projectname>ViewController.h /o/

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Console to see what reason if threw back for the crash? If you could post it it would go a long way to helping solve the reason for you app throwing sigkill.

You might try just in case a clean build , under build clean all targets then run if it crashes check the console log for what it threw if something that no longer exists is still hooked up in the Interface builder it could be a reason for the crash.